# join lists within a list with separators

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists, here is my reproducible data:

```
data <- list(list("1", "David"), list("Sarah", "4"), list("Clare"), list(
"3"))
```

I want to unite the elements within a list with & and unite the lists with the seperator |.

I would want the data to look like this:

```
1&David|Sarah&4|Clare|3
```

The closest I have managed to get is with this code:

```
data <- dplyr::bind_cols(purrr::flatten(data))
as.vector(apply(data, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse="&")))
```

But this gives the following result, which is not what I want:

```
1&David&Sarah&4&Clare&3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste` two times, inside and outside the loop.

```
paste(sapply(data, paste, collapse="&"), collapse="|")
# [1] "1&David|Sarah&4|Clare|3"
```